# How to resolve 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have created a container view controller with 3 controllers in it and this is the second view controller (VC). I have this error when I moved first VC in place of second and second VC in first VC:

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'Programs''

```
NSEntityDescription *entitydesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Programs" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
    request.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"programId" ascending:YES]];


request.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"startTime" ascending:NO], [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"day" ascending:YES]];
```

My view controller code

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
controller1 = [[Home alloc]initWithNibName:@"Home" bundle:nil];
}
else
{
    controller1 = [[Home alloc]initWithNibName:@"Home_iPad" bundle:nil];
}
controller1.title = @"Home";
controller1.delegate2 = self;

controller2 = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Activity"];
controller2.title = @"Activity";
controller2.delegate = self;


if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
controller3 = [[League alloc] initWithNibName:@"League" bundle:nil];
}
else
{
    controller3 = [[League alloc] initWithNibName:@"League_iPad" bundle:nil];
}
controller3.title = @"League";



//    controller4 = [[Messages alloc] initWithNibName:@"Messages" bundle:nil];
//    controller4.title = @"Message";



NSArray *controllerArray = @[ controller2,controller1, controller3];
```

Comment: Can you check whether your entity name is exactly "Programs"?

Comment: Yes my entity name is Programs